# How to prevent combobox changing together?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a windows form with two combo Boxes on it and fill it by my list.

When I change my fist combo Box value why is the second combo Box value changing like the first one?

How can I prevent it?

I set no event or something that can cause this problem.

```
        List<Myclass> mc = new List<Myclass>();
        mc.Add(new Myclass() {  ID = 10, Name = "No 10" });
        mc.Add(new Myclass() { ID = 27, Name = "No 27" });

        comboBox1.DataSource = mc;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

        comboBox2.DataSource = mc;
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

my class :

```
  class Myclass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: (Off-topic advice: You should set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` after setting `DataSource`, not before it.)

Comment: Reason is you are using the same data source @motevillizadeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like that because the comboboxes have the same datasource.
Try copying or cloning the list so the comboboxes have independent datasources.

Comment: ... or, instead of cloning the whole data source, perhaps put a BindingSource between it and the UI control?